To develop scheduling rest client
I am trying to develop scheduling rest client.
The task is:

There is Rest API
I would like to send GET requests on schedule

I created the Spring boot application:
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class IntegrationApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(IntegrationApplication.class, args);
    }

}

I created the scheduler config:
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "scheduler.enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
public class SchedulerConfig { }

I created java class which send requests to rest API:
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Service
public class GetAllData {

    @Value("${server.url}")
    private String serverUrl;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.clientSecret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    private static RestClientGetExecute restClientGetExecute;

    public void get() {
        // Do send request 
    }
}

Finally, I created java class which initiates request sending, as I am expecting:
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

@Component
public class TestEngine {
    private static GetAllData getAllData;
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 2000)
    public void getLocalDateTimeFixedDelay() throws InterruptedException {
        getAllData.get();
    }
}

But it doesn't work. The error is:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke GetAllData.get()" because "TestEngine.getAllData" is null

Could you help me please to find out how to run schedule sending requests to REST API?

you didnt autowire GetAllData, also autowiring wont work on static variables unless you use setter injection

Where do you setting getAllData field?

The problem is your TestEngine there is nothing in there for Spring to determine what it needs to autowire. No @Autowired on a field or a single constructor that takes a dependency. Next to that even if there would have been an @Autowired it wouldn't work as static fields cannot be injected.
Change your TestEngine to something like this. Change the field to final instead of static and add a constructor that takes the dependency.
Component
public class TestEngine {
    private final GetAllData getAllData;

    public TestEngine(GetAllData getAllData) {
      this.getAllData=getAllData;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 2000)
    public void getLocalDateTimeFixedDelay() throws InterruptedException {
        getAllData.get();
    }
}

This obviously applies to the static field in the GetAllData as well as that has a static field as well.
@Service
public class GetAllData {

    @Value("${server.url}")
    private String serverUrl;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.clientSecret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    private final RestClientGetExecute restClientGetExecute;

    public GetAllData(RestClientGetExecute restClientGetExecute) {
      this.restClientGetExecute=restClientGetExecute;
    }

    public void get() {
        // Do send request 
    }
}

If there are other places in which you use static for dependencies that should be injected switch them to constructor arguments instead.
